How can I access a locked garage through the overhead door with the lock release cord missing?
No electricity and the lock release cord is not attached so I can't pull to release.  There is a hole where the release lock should be, but the previous owner removed it so there is just a hole.  I have the key for the bottom locking mechanism near the handle.
There are 10 garages side by side attached. My garage is the center one, and the only access to the inside of my garage is by opening the garage door.
I am on the outside of the garage so in essence I am locked out and do not have access to attach a new cord (I have one just did not have time to install before the hurricane hit. i do not have a picture, but the missing emergency release lock was removed. The hole for the lock is center of door about 6 to 8 inches from the top of the door. I have tried a coat hanger through the open hole but fishing blindly and not sure what I am fishing for seen as there is not a emergency cord to snag.
How do I get in my garage?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Buy a (person) door (i.e. 3x7 hinged slab exterior door) and some framing lumber.
Go to the other side of the building from the stuck garage door.
Cut a hole. Enter the garage, use the framing lumber to frame out a door rough opening, install the door.
Alternatively, arrange for & purchase a new garage door with installation. Destructively open the old garage door and have the new garage door installed to replace it.
